# Changing the elements on a page iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to change the elements on a screen after a certain time, So to explain it a bit better I want the user to be able to put in a number in a text field, that number is stored then after 5 seconds another text field pops up and the user can enter another number. The app isn't that basic but I just need to know how to do something like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) or [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with either one of:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                     selector:@selector(yourFunction:)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES];
```

or

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourFunction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

This is a change over the UIView so it is better to do it in viewDidAppear

Comment: Thanks :) got somewhat of the basics going

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer to execute code after a number of seconds. Don't forget to add the timer to the run loop after you create it.

Example,

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(aMethodToBeCalled)
                                                           userInfo:nil
                                                            repeats:NO]
                             forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

You can use UITextFieldDelegate to know when did the use finish typing.

Answer (score 0):

Even better use Grand Central Dispatch.

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // Perform your method...
});
```